# IE10< svg max-width does not set correct proportions

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have prepared a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uj0uhkkq/1/

```
<div class="papa">
    <img src="image.svg" />
</div>

<style>
.papa {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
.papa>img {
  max-width: 250px; 
  max-height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

In IE 10 and below the image looks like this:

[image]

...in any other "recent" Browser the svg has correct proportions.

**Is there any way to fix this for IE 10 and below? If not maybe Javascript can calculate the dimensions?**

(Why do I not just set the actual height and width of the svg??? Well because I have the img-element load svg-logos of clients dynamically - of course each has different dimensions)

Comment: remove the max-height rule... the common design pattern for scaled images is to size the image to its parent element as a percent. eg. <img scr="image.svg" style="width:80%"/>... specify either height or width for the image to be rendered with the calculated natural aspect ratio.

Comment: Rob. Because the svg can be either wider or higher than the ratio of 250px/50px setting the width OR height to 100% does not work. You say "calculated natural aspect ratio" what do you mean by that? (I said the container "papa" can be loaded with any svg size I do not know before)

Answer (score 0):

the natural height/width of the svg image is 601x601 (see source for https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/I-8_%28AZ%29.svg), viz a square... so the max-height (or height) and max-width (or width) rules must be the same to maintain the aspect ratio....

```
    <div class="papa">
    <img src="image.svg" />
</div>

<style>
.papa {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
.papa>img {
  width: 50px; 
  margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The papa element must be maximum of 50px height and max of 250px width (as per my initial question) and the svg needs to scale to that. Your answer does not do that: https://jsfiddle.net/uj0uhkkq/6/